# Where did this switchmap's argument come from?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm currently following Jogesh Muppala's Angular course on Coursera, and the issue is with the following line of code.

```
   this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishService.getDish(+params['id'])))
```

The rest of the code is below. My understanding so far is that this.route.params is an Observable, and that this.dishService.getDish(+params[id]) will also return an Observable. My issue is understanding how the (params: Params) got there. It's used as the parameters in the arrow function, and that gets used by the getDish function near the end of the statement. However,  at the start of the line we could only access params via this.route.params. Is it a different params? The type declaration params: Params makes it look like it's a completely new instance of a Params type. But if so, how could it be used by getDish?

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Params, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import{ Dish} from '../shared/dish';
import { DishService} from '../services/dish.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dishdetail',
  templateUrl: './dishdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dishdetail.component.scss']
})
export class DishdetailComponent implements OnInit {

  dish: Dish;
  dishIds: number[];
  prev: number;
  next: number;


  constructor(private dishService: DishService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dishService.getDishIds().subscribe(dishIds => this.dishIds = dishIds);
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishService.getDish(+params['id'])))
    .subscribe(dish => { this.dish = dish; this.setPrevNext(dish.id); });
  }

  setPrevNext(dishId: number) {
    const index = this.dishIds.indexOf(dishId);
    this.prev = this.dishIds[(this.dishIds.length + index - 1) % this.dishIds.length];
    this.next = this.dishIds[(this.dishIds.length + index + 1) % this.dishIds.length];
  }


  goBack(): void{
      this.location.back();
  }

}
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit like this:

```
const bmw = {
  type: car,
  attributes: {
    color: 'red',
    year: 2000
  }
}

const attributes = bmw.attributes;
```

We happen to name two different things with the same name `attributes`: one is a variable and the other is a property in an object. They are not related except by the unfortunate coincidence of sharing the same name.

In your case, in `this.route.params`, params is a property in `this.route` which returns an Observable.

`(params: Params) => this.dishService...` is an anonymous function which would be the same as writing `(function anon(params: Params) { this.dishService... }).bind(this)`. Here, `params` is name given to the argument that the function receives.

The above function executes when a new value is emitted on the Observable from `this.routes.params`. The value that is emitted here is passed into the anonymous function as its argument, which happens to be called `params`. So it doesn't need a dot notation because it is not referring to the same thing: it's referring to the value that comes out of the Observable.

At the root of this though the anonymous function (the arrow function) is a function that is passed `switchMap` and this gets executed once for every value that is put on the source Observable (this.route.params). Each time it executes, switchMap passes in the current value in the Observable as that first argument `params`. SwitchMap expects this function to return to it a new Observable, which is what is returned by `this.dishService.getDish`.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The `(params: Params)` is from the `router.params` and it's the rxjs 6 way of doing observable operator chaining.

In essence what is really going on is `.pipe` takes a list of functions and each function through the list gets the value of the previous one except if it's preceded by a `tap` or `filter` etc...

So

```
this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishService.getDish(+params['id'])))
```

Before was written like

```
this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishService.getDish(+params['id']))
```

So it would get the value from `route.params` pass it into the `switchMap` operator which would return a new `Observable` of the the result from the function which you passed into it.

Comment: But how does Angular get a hold of param: Params without using the dot notation that was needed for this.route.params, and why does it declare params type?

Comment: This is more of a typescript syntax than Angular. Function composition and arrow function syntax sugar you could look at those: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/arrow/ or maybe https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: I think I understand arrow notation, what i'm unclear on is how params is being accessed within the arrow function's header without using dot notiation.

Comment: it's passed in from the `.pipe` and into the `switchMap` the `Params` is just a declaration of the variable

Comment: So the reason we don't have to access params through dot notation is because pipe provides the context?  

I knew that Params was declaring a variable, but I thought params already existed, so I 'm not clear on why it's being declared.